# C# get name of object as string

Tags: c#, object

I have an object named 'Account' and the following code:

```
Account objAcc = new Account();
objAcc.Name = "Test";
```

The above is working fine, as expected. I now have a list of values as follows:

```
string props = "Name,Address,Telephone";
```

Now, what I want to do is see if "Name" exists in that list. I only have the object to use though (hard coding a case statement etc isn't possible as the object is dynamic), so from objAcc.Name, I somehow need to get "Name" from that, and then see if it's in the list.

Thanks in advance, I hope it's clear enough,

Dave

Comment: I don't get what you want, could you give exemples of actual data, actual input and what you expect your output to be?

Comment: can you post whole code sample ?

Comment: I think [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx) may be the topic you  should have a look at!

Comment: Essentially, does the xxx part of objAcc.xxx exist in a string list - Vash you may as well not be on this site

Comment: and after understanding Reflection, you may have a look at expression trees in order to spped up your application...

Comment: how about `typeof (Account).GetProperties().Any(x => props.Contains(x.Name))`

Comment: Please! Dudes! Dont use the reflection in the runtime, it's a very bad move! This will slow down the whole application. You can use reflection once on application start!

Comment: @Vash : Why do you react this way `Go and find some tutorial` ? If this is a duplicate mark it duplicate by giving a link to SO post, if you have a tutorial you already used give a link. Will **dhardy** be comfortable to ask another question here after such reaction? Who gains what with comments like this?

Comment: @MechanicalObject, I voted to close with proper note on it. The tutorial hint would help more than assumption what the question really is up to. It is not directly expressed that it is about reflection. With such vague question it is better that OP will find a tutorial as he will try to rephrase the problem into something that really exists. And with such concrete defined issue i will for sure have faster response. I could not provide him a tutorial as is unknown what the problem is.

Comment: `Vash` all of us understand what OP wants.

Comment: @Maris : no, I do not understand what OP wants. But that is no excuse to be rude as Vash once was (in a now deleted comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string test = objAcc.GetType().GetProperty("Name") == null ? "" : objAcc.GetType().GetProperty("Name").Name;
bool result = "Name,Address,Telephone".Split(',').Contains(test);
```

You may use the following method if you like:

```
public bool PropertyExists<T>(string propertyName, IEnumerable<string> propertyList,T obj)
{
    string test = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName) == null ? "" : obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).Name;
    bool result = propertyList.Contains(test);
    return result;
}
```

Giannis

Comment: The ? operator is redundant in this case.

Comment: Note that method argument should be not capitalized. And the List<string> as parameter is quite limiting, the IEnumerable<string> would support the linq. Hope that helps ;-).

Comment: I will edit, but why not capitalize? Should i use camel or no capitals? This is just formatting isn't it?

Comment: To be totally correct it should lower camel case. It more about coding convetion thatn formating. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff926074.aspx.

Comment: @Vash Once more thanks for the constructive comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection, by doing that :

```
var properties = objAcc.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach(var property in properties)
{
  if(props.Contains(property.Name))
  {
     //Do you stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Please! Dudes! Dont use the reflection in the runtime, it's a very bad move! This will slow down the whole application. You can use reflection once on application start!

Comment: You have a point in there @Maris, but if you use it with moderation it is a powerful tool :-).

Comment: Agree with your opinion Houssem. But as I said, you should use reflection only once per application life-time and the result of reflection should be cached. But if you use it always in the runtime you will get the slow-down of whole application. You will recieve a performance issue

Comment: Just looking for the name in the string will give false positives, as the Contains method doesn't know that you think that it's a comma separated list of names. With the example string it would also return true for properties named for example `Add`, `phone`, `dress`, `me` and `one`.

Comment: well yes, but perfecting it is for the one who wil include it in his/her solution. the question was how to get a property name dynamicly? and that is just what the answer is :).